# Type classes - Brief Explanation

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I am new to Haskell and i come from c++ background.

I am having some trouble understanding the relation between types and type classes.

From what i understand type classes specify a bunch of functions. Like the `Eq` type class specifies `==` and `/=`.

But now suppose i have a type `t`, What does it mean when i say that `t` is an instance of `Eq` type class. Does it simply mean that `t` supports and implements the functions specified by `Eq` ?

Comment: In Java, typeclasses might be seen as *interfaces*.

Comment: @AJFarmar m not familiar with java sorry.

Comment: Okay then, what if I said *abstract classes* from C++?

Comment: Well, you just learnt some Haskell and Java concepts. Today is a good day.

Comment: @AJFarmar also my question did not get downvoted, a good day indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it simply mean that t supports and implements the functions specified by Eq ?

Yes, precisely.

It simply means that there's an instance of `Eq t` which defines the operator `(==)`, as required by `Eq`. You can therefore use said operator on type `t` in your code.

A silly example:

```
data MyPair = P Int String

instance Eq MyPair where
   (P i1 s1) == (P i2 s2) =   -- we define equality ...
      i1==i2 && s1==S2        -- ... as component-wise equality

testTrue :: Bool
testTrue = (P (1+1) "aa") == (P 2 ("a"++"a"))
```

In the example above, the common idiom would actually be

```
data MyPair = P Int String deriving Eq
```

which automatically derives the instance -- so there's no need to write it explicitly.

Comment: @AneeshDandime Keep in mind that if you had something like `Eq a => [a]` (a list of values implementing `Eq`), the list is still homogeneous.  In OOP languages you can "downcast" different classes to the "Eq interface" and store them all in the same structure, but not in Haskell, downcasting has to be performed manually.